# Is a process started from a web form stopped when IIS shuts down the application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, webforms, iis-7

I have an old web form application that spawns a process when an ImageButton is pressed:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process someProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

someProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "path goes here";
someProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
someProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "SomeProcess.exe";
someProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "arguments goes there";

someProcess.Start();
```

The process has a variable duration but it is somewhat long running.

Is it possible that IIS shuts down the application before the process is completed?

Comment: Isn't it faster to try yourself and see the result?

Comment: Yes. When the app pool recycles, this process will receive a command to be killed. It might not listen though. So it depends on the process.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars What? Since when?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have actually tried stopping manually the web site from IIS console. The process gets killed before completion. I wasn't sure it is the same behaviour when IIS stopped the application by itself

Comment: @mason I have observed app pool recycles as well as explicit kills, kill both background workers and spawned processes in the wild. This might have been a mistaken correlation/causality though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kill command will be given, it depends on the process and its settings on whether or not the kill command will actually be executed prior to work being finished.

In other words; this is something you should and can easily test yourself.

Comment: As stated in the question comment I tried manually stopping the web site from IIS console. I wasn't sure IIS does the same when stopping the application by itself

Comment: @sblandin I read over that. To answer your question: yes, both situations use the same underlying command.